# Are excited states broader?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Consider the 1D Schroedinger equation with some potential $V(x)$. Let the ground state $\psi_0$ be centered around $x = 0$. If $\psi_1$ is the first excited state, is it true that for all potentials
$$\int dx\, x^2\, (|\psi_1(x)|^2 - |\psi_0(x)|^2)>0$$

Comment: In general (i.e., any $V(x)$) no. The free particle is a counter example where $\left|\psi_n\right|$ are all the same ($=1$) but $E_n$ varies. You may be able to prove this for some bound systems but not all because Landau states also act as a counter example.

Comment: Thanks, good insight. But yes, I guess I meant only potential models (so no vector potential as in Landau levels). Also, the continuous spectrum is a bit odd, the variance is ill defined and all. I appreciate the insight anyways.

Comment: A SE with a time-invariant potential doesn't give us line widths to begin with. The discrete spectrum is a point spectrum. Transition probabilities and lifetimes only enter into the equation if we allow for a time dependent perturbation by an external field. The line widths will increase with the strength of the coupling to this field. None of this is "physical", it's just a model system. If we want to calculate the "correct" line widths for atomic physics, for instance, we have to do a quantum electrodynamics calculation which goes beyond the simple SE approach.

Comment: see example of http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/h21.htmlthe fine structure here